# Generate temporary URL to reset password

Tags: url, passwords, reset

I am looking to implement a Forgot Password feature on my website. I like the option where an email containing a temporary one-time use URL that expires after some time is sent to the user.

I have looked at the following pages to get these ideas but I am not sure how to implement this using ASP.NET and C#.  As one of the users indicated, if I can implement this without storing this information inside the database, that will be ideal.  Please advise.

[Password reset by emailing temporary passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306942/password-reset-by-emailing-temporary-passwords)

Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you could encrypt information, in a format similar to the following format

```
(UserId)-(ExpireDate)
```

Encrypt the data, make that the link, then decrypt the data and take action from there...

Crude, but most likely usable, and not requiring DB usage

Comment: It's a bad practice to include any data into password reset token. Event if it's encrypted. A hacker who knows the algorithm will be able to reset password for any user even with no access to user's mailbox.

Comment: -1. The idea is good in a sense but it should NOT be used because of security issue that Slava explained in previous comment.

Comment: @SlavaNadvorny A Hacker will need to know the key to the encryption algorithm as well. You can assume that if the hacker has access to the encryption key, he probably also has access to the stored hashes, so yes this technique still seems like a good idea.

Comment: The real problem with this technique is that it cannot prevent multiple use of the same reset token.

Comment: @Guillaume I'd agree, BUT since it is user tied, that isn't as big of a deal.  If the user had the ability to store to the DB or was willing it would be easier

Comment: One could also make a hash from like UserId-Salt-yyyyMMddHH, use it in a link together with an identifier. 

Serverside this hash can be recreated (with the use of the identifier) with a date format of the current hour en the previous hour, if one matches you know for sure that the hash is at most ~2 hours old.

Comment: @Slava Nadvorny  Thats true.

Answer (score 76):

Probably the easiest way is going to be to modify your users table to add 2 extra columns, OR if you don't want to modify the existing table you could add a new dependent table called "UserPasswordReset" or something like that.  The columns are like this:

```
PasswordResetToken UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
PasswordResetExpiration DATETIME
```

If you go with the additional table route, you could do also add the UserID column, make it a primary key and a foriegn key reference back to your users table.  A UNIQUE constraint would also be recommended.  Then you simply use a Guid in your asp.net application as the token.

The flow could be something like this:

1. User requests password reset for their account
2. You insert a new record in the table (or update their user record) by setting the PasswordResetExpiration to a date in the future  (DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)), and set the token to Guid.NewGuid()
3. Email the user a link to your ResetPassword.aspx page with the guid in the query string (http://www.yoursite.com/ResetPassword.aspx?token=Guid-here)
4. Use the ResetPassword.aspx page to validate the token and expiration fields.  (I.E. Make sure DateTime.Now < PasswordResetExpiration)
5. Provide a simple form that allows the user to reset this password.

I know you wanted to avoid modifying the database, but it really is probably the simplest method.

Comment: Security Note : UNIQUEIDENTIFIER are not meant to provide randomness and are insecure in this scenario. Basically, you want a reset link that is impossible to guess. In order to make it impossible to guess your reset link, you need to include a random number generated by a cryptographically secure random number generator which a GUID is not. So, in addition to your 2 columns you need a third one to store that random number that will act as your password and finally you send the GUID and the password in the reset link as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

@Alex

You can also use System.Security.Cryptography classes in .NET for the hash algorithms. For example:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
var hash = SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(myTokenToHash);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, the System.Guid class in your friend, as it will generate a unique (well, unique enough) 128-bit number:

- Generate a new Guid ( System.Guid.NewGuid() )
- Store that Guid somewhere (Application object maybe?)
- Send a custom URL in an email with that Guid
- When the user hits the site, make them enter the password you sent in the email
- If the passwords match, go ahead and force them to enter a new password

Comment: GUID are supposed to be unique, but not supposed to be cryptographically strong. It might be possible to guess which GUID will be created and thus create a token for a specific account.

Comment: @Guillaume, thanks for the info, really is it possible ? Can you explain a bit about how it can be guessed ? I was thinking about using GUID.

Comment: That probably require a separate question focused on GUID. In short, GUID are usually generated based on some guessable inputs (MAC address, timestamps, ...) and a random part. The part that is hard to guess is the random part, which is not necessarily large, so probably not as difficult to guess as it should to provide security.

In very short : GUID are meant to be unique, they are not meant to be hard to guess.

Comment: Unique != Random. Guid's can be predictable, and should not be used when needing a random token.

Answer (score 1):

I used a Hashing Class to create unique automatic logins made up of the current date/time and the users email address:

```
string strNow = DateTime.Now.ToString();
string strHash = strNow + strEmail;
strHash = Hash.GetHash(strHash, Hash.HashType.SHA1);
```

get the Hash Class from: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4601/create-hashes-md5-sha1-sha256-sha384-sha512/

Then just take it from the URL using:

```
if (Request.QueryString["hash"] != null)
{
                //extract Hash from the URL
                string strHash = Request.QueryString["hash"];
}
```

Comment: how would you get back the email address & datetime from hash again so that you can login automatically? Because hashes are one way right?. Please educate.

Comment: @goths you could store the Hash value in the database as well as sending an email containing a URL with the user id and hash appended. Then on the page that the URL points to, compare the 2 against the database. That would be a basic solution, you'd need something more robust for something needing better security.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the utility to send any information in the hash coded key if the point is to store it next to the same info in the DB. The only think you need is a unique key, not a encrypted version of any "real" information. The randow unique generated id as proposed by Goyuix (see his answer) is just the best choice if you have to have something send AND stored in the DB to be able to find it back when the user click on the link within the sent email.

Comment: How validate the hash ?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely include the database in this process. Once a reset is requested, it's a good idea to indicate that the account is locked out.

For example, if you are changing your pw because you think your account may have been compromised, you definitely don't want it to remain accessible while you go about the change process.

Also, inclusion of "real" information in the reset token could be decoded if someone really wants it and has the horsepower. It would be safer to generate a random string, save it in the db in the row for that user, and then key back to it when the link is clicked.

This gives you two things:

1) There's nothing to decrypt, and therefore nothing of value can be gained from it.
2) The presence of the token in the user record indicates that reset is in progress and the account should be treated as locked out.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of sending some data|string to user email is validation of account owner. Please care about some points:

- Avoid sending important information in reset or activate link.
- It's best way to store unique string data conjunction with user
  account and send it as that link. but be aware if you send just one
  section as link to user email and just check it in page, your
  application may be in dangerous by brute-force or dictionary
  attacker. It's enough to check a list of string to find some links
  and change password. I know that has a little chance, but not zero.

Result:
I think it's better if you

1. combine user email with string link then encrypt them
   (not hash because hashed value can't be reverse) and send to user
   email.
2. User click and your page get the encrypted value.
3. decrypt value.
4. extract user email.
5. find email in database.
6. compare string from received link with other one attached to user
   email in database.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a hash code to validate details in the password reset url. This can all be done without writing anything to the DB or sending any privileged info to an attaker.

To briefly explain normal password salt and hashing; say the salt is `1111` and the pasword is `password`, you'd concatenate the two and hash the string `1111password`, say this gives you a hash of `9999`, you'd then store the original salt `1111` and hash `9999` in your user record.

When you are validating a password you use the stored salt, concatenate the password attempt, hash it and compare with the stored hash. For example `asecret` becomes `1111asecret` but hashes to `8888`. This doesn't match the original hash so the password match fails.

Of course the salt and hash would normally be properly generated and calculated with established crypto libraries (don't invent your own!).

For the password reset URL I'd put in the unique identifier for the user, i.e. email address, the date the request is made, and a new hash. This hash would be generated from those details concatenated together plus the salt and hash already stored for the user.

For example:

```
Email: user@example.com
Request Date: 2014-07-17
Salt: 1111
Hash: 9999
```

Generate a new hash of those concatenated, i.e. `'user@example.com2014-07-1711119999'`, say this gives a hash of `7777`.

The URL I then generate would then have the email, request date and the new hash:

```
https:\\www.example.com\ResetPassword?email=user@example.com&requestdate=2014-07-17&hash=7777
```

The server will combine the email and supplied date with it's salt and hash and confirm the hash it generated is the same as the supplied one. If this is Ok then it will show the reset form with the same three parameters hidden behind it, otherwise an error. These get resubmitted and rechecked when the new password is entered to prevent that form being spoofed.

The email address needs to be supplied to make the request and it is only sent out in an email to the same address. the date is hardly priveleged info and the hash is not reversible so gives nothing anyway. Nothing has been written to the database and any tampering with the parameters causes the hash to fail and the URL to report an error.

Comment: There is an issues with this approach. A safe hash makes the token really long. Either you integrate the salt into the hash itself (makes it about 20 charactes longer), or you store this unique salt in the database. If you store the salt in the database, you could as well store a random token which is not derrived from any existing data.

Comment: @martinstoeckli As you are already hashing a salt in the concatenated string there is no need to add another. The OP did request that it wasn't stored in the DB. 

Though you are right, the url is long and a proper hash will make it longer, but I'd expect the link to be clicked, or copied and pasted, so I don't think it's too much of an issue.

Comment: What i meant is, that the salt must be contained in readable form in the link, otherwise it is a key not a salt. A salt is unique per token, and this must be either stored in the db or you can extract it from the url.

Comment: any full source code for generate hash and validate hash ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issues with this approach. A safe hash makes the token really long. Either you integrate the salt into the hash itself (makes it about 20 charactes longer), or you store this unique salt in the database. If you store the salt in the database, you could as well store a random token which is not derrived from any existing